# How to create a product display view showing all users who purchased a product through a specific display

Tags: views, commerce

Im looking to create a view which will have an exposed filter of Product Display Titles in a select list and then display a table of users who purchased a product which originated from that display. The product will be used on multiple displays so this is important to get that filter. Im really struggling to achieve this and so far am getting it to display users for a product but not the display.

It seems the only indicator of the original product display is the display path. I thought I had cracked it but its just not working. If anyone can have a go or walk me through it that would be amazing.

Thanks all

Comment: Hi GAMe, I'm finding it a little difficult to understand what your content / data looks like. Is there any chance you could provide some screenshots so that we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

Your view needs to have this relationship setup, with multiple relationships added so you can relate your entities in this way.

Product Display > Product > Order > User

I should be able to provide a stronger answer if you can provide a little more detail, but have struggled with a similar view I had to create about 2 years ago and remember it taking a few days for me to resolve :)

Good luck!